# Logging Web API calls MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, logging, asp.net-web-api

I need to log to the database every call to my Web API.
Now of course I don't want to go to my database on every call.

So lets say I have a dictionary or a hash table object in my cache,
and every 10000 records I go to the database.

I still don't want this every 10000 user to wait for this operation.
And I can't start a different thread for long operations since the application pool
can be recycled basically on anytime.

What is the best solution for this scenario?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would argue that your view of durability is rather inconsistent. Your cache of 10000 objects could also be lost at any time due to an app pool recycle or server crash.

But to the original question of how to perform a large operation without causing the user to wait:

- Put constraints on app pool recycling and deal with the potential data loss.
- Periodically dump the cached messages to a Windows service for further processing. This is still not 100% guaranteed to preserve data, e.g. the service/server could crash.
- Use a message queue ([MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472.aspx)), [possibly with WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789048.aspx). A message queue can persist to disk, so this can be considered reasonably reliable.

> Message Queuing (MSMQ) technology enables applications running at
>   different times to communicate across heterogeneous networks and
>   systems that may be temporarily offline. Applications send messages to
>   queues and read messages from queues.
>
> Message Queuing provides guaranteed message delivery, efficient
>   routing, security, and priority-based messaging. It can be used to
>   implement solutions to both asynchronous and synchronous scenarios
>   requiring high performance.

Taking this a step further...

Depending on your requirements and/or environment, you could probably eliminate your cache, and write all messages immediately (and rapidly) to a message queue and not worry about performance loss *or* a large write operation.

Comment: Thanks! I actually didn't think about taking it out to a different service/queue